# RecyclerView: show favorite items marked as favorite inside the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have no problem saving items id and retrieving them, problem is
when I try to show items that is saved as favorite inside the recyclerview by checking the item id in onBindView method it shows only one item is saved as favorite.

onBindView code as below:

```
if(searchIfInFav(modelShipment.getShipmentsKey())) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: checkStatus " + searchIfInFav(modelShipment.getShipmentsKey()));
        shipmentsViewHolder.save_later.setTag(R.drawable.saved_for_later);
        shipmentsViewHolder.save_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.saved_for_later);
    }else {
        shipmentsViewHolder.save_later.setTag(R.drawable.save);
        shipmentsViewHolder.save_later.setImageResource(R.drawable.save);
    }
```

and the iterator method as below:

```
private boolean searchIfInFav(String key) {
    boolean match = false;
    for(String mKey : similarKeys){
        Log.d(TAG, "onBindViewHolder: checkStatus loop " + mKey);
        if(mKey.equals(key)){
            match = true;
        }else {
            match = false;
        }
    }
    return match;
```

}

the imageButton is filled for only one item although list has more ids.

Comment: `if(mKey.equals(key)){match = true;}else{match = false;}` which makes **match** depends only on the last data of _similarKeys_. Try removed `else{match = false;}`. Hope that helps!

Comment: @i_A_mok it worked, thanks alot, sure you can make it an answer and I will confirm it correct answer.